# what file to execute BLE code

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I am writing a range finder program that uses RSSI values from bluetooth low energy.  I was wondering in what file i should write the CBPeripheral and CBCentralManager code in? I usually just stick to the viewController.h and .m files but i have never used a core feature like BLE before. Should i write this in the appDelegate files or should i make new files?  Also I want this program to be able to run in the background.  I don't know if that factors in or not, but if so feel free to tell me.

Comment: Take a look at the BTLE Transfer example. https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html For the sake of simplicity, add you CB code to a view controller. But keep in mind that this is bad practice.

Comment: SharedInstance/Singleton. This way you can access it from everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, i am using AppDelegate as the **CBCentralManagerDelegate** and the **CBPeripheralDelegate**, so i can make connected devices available anywhere within my app (i really need it, but if you don't, creating a custom class may have more sense). Maybe it is not a great practice, but for now, it works great.

For **CBCentralManager** handling, i have created a custom class, where i read, write and start scanning.